# Is it possible to create a SQL matrix from a table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I create a matrix from a single table in a SQL query? To be honest, I'm not even sure if this is possible as everyone I have asked has not been able provide any input. I have a single table with information that I need to run a comparison on. I am pulling from the Information Schema in Snowflake ("SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_ROLES") and it is structured like this:

Essentially the table needs to be pivoted and the Privilege column needs to result as some sort of Boolean value, can be True/False, or 0/1, or some other format that denotes that the role column has the given privilege to the associated row. The result will match approximately 25k rows and ~175 columns.

Table:

| Privilege | Name | Granted_On |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Select | Table1 | Role1 |
| Select | Table1 | Role2 |
| Select | Table2 | Role3 |

Result Matrix:

| Name | Role1 | Role2 | Role3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | True | True | False |
| Table2 | False | False | True |

Comment: I think you can pivot the Privilege column and use the Role column as the new column headers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by [@Haminteu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3299843/haminteu), you could use the [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot) clause to pivot the roles to columns. Something like this may do the trick:

```sql
SELECT
  Name,
  CASE WHEN "'Role1'" > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE AS Role1,
  CASE WHEN "'Role2'" > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE AS Role2,
  CASE WHEN "'Role3'" > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE AS Role3
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_ROLES"
  PIVOT(COUNT(Privilege) FOR GRANT IN ('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')) AS p
  ORDER BY Name
);
```

PS: probably you'll want to automate the roles in the `PIVOT` clause with a subquery or values coming from a CTE. Regarding the `CASE WHEN` clauses, I couldn't think how to automate them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I'm getting an error on line 3 and 9 with the 'FOR GRANT IN' clause: ***SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 60 unexpected 'AS'. syntax error line 6 at position 0 unexpected 'FROM'. syntax error line 9 at position 29 unexpected 'GRANT'.*** I think line 9 is an easy fix, but not sure about line 3...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't have a Snowflake instance available to test it! Anyway, I think the problem is `GRANT` is a reserved keyword on most DBMS, Snowflake being no exception. Try changing it to other word, maybe PRIVILEGE.